# Mule esb disable Invocation properties logs

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

How do i disable logs for message properties. I need to call Https of a web service and get the results back, but these messages came back with it in the logging. I am not allowed to show these confidential information at all.

Thanks

```
INFO  2017-05-23 15:48:06,950 [[ManulifeMay23].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=bdf0b820-3ff0-11e7-b37a-005056a37828
  payload=java.util.LinkedHashMap
  correlationId=bdeac4b0-3ff0-11e7-b37a-005056a37828
  correlationGroup=31
  correlationSeq=1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>
ESPECIALLY this invocation parts
Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
    bonusAmount=0
    bounsCounter=0
    counter=1
    cxf_operation=}getBonusPoint
    cxf_service={}ExternalServerService
    jsonVariable={selectFields=[programName, registrationDate, cycleToDateAdjustedBonusAmount, totalEarnedRedeemableBonusAmount], **common={accountId=4040320030000877}}**
    lastFourCC=0877
    operation=getBonusPoint
    payload1=[Ljava.lang.Object;@4ea65f0
    programName=
    registrationDate=
    rootMessage=<<<MuleMessage>>>
    totalAmount=0
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    connection=Keep-Alive
    content-type=application/json
    date=Tue, 23 May 2017 19:48:06 GMT
    http.reason=OK
    http.status=200
    transfer-encoding=chunked
    x-archived-client-ip=10.180.205.250
    x-backside-transport=OK OK,OK OK
    x-client-ip=10.180.205.250,10.188.196.7
    x-global-transaction-id=962389919
    x-response-code=200
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
    MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE=31
    MULE_CORRELATION_ID=bdeac4b0-3ff0-11e7-b37a-005056a37828
    MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE=1
  SESSION scoped properties:`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default log if you don't declare any value on logger. You may want to customize the value on logger so that this will not be display.

Comment: Im not sure how can I do that, is there a sample example that you could show me. Thanks

Comment: You can customize your logs through dataweave and set as payload or you can normally add string message.

 <logger message="#[payload]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>